# iwlmvm: Unknown symbol dev_coredumpm (err 0)

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, kernel-module, coredump

I want to get my WIFI Module (Intel Wireless 7265) to work.

Current Issue:

- iwlwifi loads
- iwlmvm fails to load -> Error Code: Unknown symbol
  dev_coredumpm (err 0)

Things I've already done:

- Loaded the newest firmware and placed it in /lib/firmware
- Recompiled my Kernel and my modules
- Rebootet afterwards.

Kernel 4.4.26-gentoo.

My kernel config (full config avaiable here: http://pastebin.com/epeap0Wt):

```
CONFIG_IWLWIFI=m
CONFIG_IWLWIFI_LEDS=y
CONFIG_IWLDVM=m
CONFIG_IWLMVM=m
CONFIG_IWLWIFI_OPMODE_MODULAR=y
# CONFIG_IWLWIFI_BCAST_FILTERING is not set
# CONFIG_IWLWIFI_UAPSD is not set
# CONFIG_IWLWIFI_DEBUG is not set
CONFIG_IWLWIFI_DEVICE_TRACING=y

CONFIG_COREDUMP=y
CONFIG_WANT_DEV_COREDUMP=y
CONFIG_ALLOW_DEV_COREDUMP=y
CONFIG_DEV_COREDUMP=y

CONFIG_MODULES=y
# CONFIG_MODULE_FORCE_LOAD is not set
CONFIG_MODULE_UNLOAD=y
CONFIG_MODULE_FORCE_UNLOAD=y
# CONFIG_MODVERSIONS is not set
# CONFIG_MODULE_SRCVERSION_ALL is not set
# CONFIG_MODULE_SIG is not set
# CONFIG_MODULE_COMPRESS is not set
CONFIG_MODULES_TREE_LOOKUP=
```

dmesg output:

```
[13406.402497] Intel(R) Wireless WiFi driver for Linux
[13406.402500] Copyright(c) 2003- 2015 Intel Corporation
[13406.402865] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-7265D-19.ucode failed with error -2
[13406.402880] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-7265D-18.ucode failed with error -2
[13406.402885] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-7265D-17.ucode failed with error -2
[13406.403453] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: loaded firmware version 16.242414.0 op_mode iwlmvm
[13406.404341] iwlmvm: Unknown symbol dev_coredumpm (err 0)
[13406.409747] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: failed to load module iwlmvm (error 256), is dynamic loading enabled?
```

Dynamic firmware loading build into the kernel, every option i found including "coredump" is too.

In my opinion I'm missing something that has to be installed/configured in order to use dev_coredumpm.

Any suggestions how to fix this? Nothing I found worked.
Thanks for your help!

**Edit 1:** 
If I enable UNUSED_SYMBOLS iwlwifi refuses to recognize my device and does not load any firmware.
Additional my USB Ethernet Interface stops working.

**Edit 2:**
I found iwlwifi-7265D-19.ucode and placed them in /lib/firmware. The error stays.

```
[ 1515.440212] Intel(R) Wireless WiFi driver for Linux
[ 1515.440213] Copyright(c) 2003- 2015 Intel Corporation
[ 1515.441032] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: loaded firmware version 19.324151.0 op_mode iwlmvm
[ 1515.441864] iwlmvm: Unknown symbol dev_coredumpm (err 0)
[ 1515.448057] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: failed to load module iwlmvm (error 256), is dynamic loading enabled?
```

**Final:** I could not resolve the issue. Going with another distro on that particular laptop.